# Executing Java in Mono C# Runtime (Linux)

Tags: java, c#

I try to execute Java code in a C# application running Mono on Linux and stumbled over the http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/java/ tutorial. It states it uses IKVM.net which points to a source-forge repository which is five years old (2012).

If this is not supported by Mono anymore, what other ways exist to run Java code along within a C# application running on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

IKVM appears to still be the supported tool for doing what you want. But the repository seems to have moved. Try poking in at GitHub instead, there's a [fork repository](https://github.com/mono/ikvm-fork) there that seems more up to date.